# Multi Select ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем привет! Пишу WPF приложение, используя MVVM паттерн. У меня есть комбобокс с множественным выбором элементов, то есть элементом комбобокса является чекбокс. Я взял уже его готовое решение [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF). К комбобоксу я привязал коллекцию большого размера (> 1500 элементов). Проблема состоит в том, что при выборе всех элементов сразу(например через элемент чек-бокса "All" ) или при сбросе SelectedItems = null, происходит зависание комбобокса на несколько секунд. Если лезть в логику, это происходит когда каждому элементу комбобокса isChecked проставляется в false или true. У меня стоит win 7. Если запускать приложение через rdp или на win 8 и старше - комбобокс работает идеально. Я так понимаю это как то связано с графикой wpf. Подскажите как решить данную проблему.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать VirtualizingStackPanel в качестве контейнера для checkbox'ов. К сожалению на win7 проверить не смогу

Comment: Комбобокс предназначен для небольших коллекций. Пользователю работать со списком в 1500 элементов физически сложно. Почему бы вместо этого не использовать всплывающую форму в которой можно делать сортировку, применять фильтры и асинхронное отображение массовых операций.